# Saving a byte array to PDF file with OfficeJs

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, office-js

Using OfficeJs I want to save a Word document as a PDF and post that file to an Api.

[Office.context.document.getFileAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync) will let you get the entire document in a choice of 3 formats:

- **compressed**: returns the entire document (.pptx or .docx) in Office Open XML (OOXML) format as a byte array
- **pdf**: returns the entire document in PDF format as a byte array
- **text**: returns only the text of the document as a string. (Word only)

I am posting the PDF byte array to a WebApi action that looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload([FromBody]byte[] bytes)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\testpdf.pdf", bytes);
    return Ok();
}
```

On inspection the byte array is the same array created by the getFileAsync from Office Js.

The problem is the file written in `File.WriteAllBytes` is corrupt. If I open it with notepad, it is a string of the bytes - `37,80,68,70,45,49,46,53,13,10,37... and so on`.

Any idea why the method WriteAllBytes does not create a PDF file from the OfficeJS pdf byte stream?

### UPDATE 25/5/16

As hawkeye @StefanHegny pointed out, the byte array appears to be Ascii characters. Converting each byte to `char` and writing that out to PDF like this creates a blank PDF, but on inspection with NotePad, the contents do like a like a PDF document, though quite different to that when saving the same .docx as a .pdf.

```
var content = "";
foreach (var b in model.Bytes)
{
    content += (char) b;
}

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\testpdf.pdf", content);
```

Also note, this is extremely slow - about 5 minutes for 500kb PDF byte array on my dev machine.

Comment: 37,80,68,70 looks like "%" (=ASCII 37) "P" "D" "F" which is the pdf file magic number, so that may well be the bytes of a pdf file so to me it looks okay if treated as a sequence of bytes with that value. But your question is why the bytes are written out as decimal values?

Comment: Wow, well spotted @StefanHegny! Yes, why a sequence of decimals, and not the PDF gunk that you usually see when looking at a PDF with NotePad?

Comment: Have you tried using `File.WriteAllText(Encoding.Ascii.GetString(model.Bytes)` ?

Comment: Not until you mentioned it @Chrisi. Unfortunately it creates the same document as the code from UPDATE 25/5/16 - A PDF document that has the same number of pages, but is only whitespace.

Comment: Damn, PDFshould be ANSI encoded text files. when you open them in notepad, you can kinda see the basic structure. it should start with `%PDF-1.4` and occaisionally have something like `1 0 obj` (or other numbers). can you check your created PDF in notepad?

Comment: The format text of the PDF looks correct. This is the one created with Save As Pdf in word https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=50BB460A5606F468!22094&authkey=!AFlx0WFSUZCuoLI&ithint=file%2cpdf, this is the one created from the OfficeJs byte array https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=50BB460A5606F468!22093&authkey=!AF3H6zfkJEMa6zE&ithint=file%2cpdf

Comment: Looking at the text of your pdf, i noticed in line 2 that word puts `%µµµµ` while your app writes `%????` So I'd try using `File.WriteAllText(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(model.Bytes))` or play around with other encodings, since this might be the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112936/discussion-between-marvin-rounce-and-chrisi).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same pdf empty problem, and it was because I was converting to string and writing string to file(encoding problem), I solved by sending to the c# code the comma separated byte codes instead of converting to string, parsing bytes and using `File.WriteAllBytes()`

C# code:

```
     string[] strings = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(pdf).Split(',');

     byte[] bytes = strings.Select(s => byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();

     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("filename.pdf", bytes);
```